# resource leak : serversocket is never closed when using while loop for getting client requests

Tags: java, server, client, serversocket

I tried to find in exact solution for this problem but I'm not able to find it

I have written a while loop to accept client sockets in server program

because of this I'm unable to close the serversocket as it is always listening

here is my server code

```
public class nserver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int port=4413;
    //server is running on port
    try(ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port)){;
    // socket accepts data from the incoming clients
        while(true){
            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            // id I don't put the if case then this loop never breaks and 
            // although I wrote ss.close() - it will never reached - so use if case
            if(socket.equals(null))
                break;
            System.out.println("Server is running on port "+port);
            //socket.getInetAddress gives address of client ip not the server ip as the socket is mada as client socket
            System.out.println("server recieved connection from "+socket.getInetAddress()+" : "+socket.getPort());
            //create two threads to send and receive from client

            rxClientData rx = new rxClientData(socket);
            Thread t = new Thread(rx);
            t.start();

            sdServerData sd = new sdServerData(socket);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(sd);
            t2.start();

          // if I put ss.close() here then it will accept only one client socket and serversocket will be closed after this line
        }
        ss.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

how to close serversocket after my client socket requests,I have 3 clients

with for loop I will have a limit of no.of client sockets,but a server should accept  so many no.of requests - so I used while loop

for a server do we need to keep serversocket open in real world scenario ? - so that it accepts client requests all the time

Comment: Why have you got the socket accept inside an infinite loop?

Comment: I have multiple clients ,so I need to create multiple socket accept,if I use a for loop I will be limited by a number,if in I increase the number of clients in future then it is a problem.my goal is to create something near to a real world server where it accepts so many no.of requests i.e socket accepts

Comment: when I did as you said ,it  never reached the line below the if case - so never a thread was created

Comment: Of course - daft moment from me. The loop wouldn't get started properly because it hasn't been accepted yet. Apologies. I'll take away the other comment ;)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on this myself. I found some links if you haven;t already read them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001204/how-to-close-serversocket-connection-when-catching-ioexception
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385452/serversocket-is-it-really-necessary-to-close-it

Comment: Other people seem to be putting the accept inside a `try/catch`. Then you can put the close inside the `finally` part. Although I think that once it is finished with the `try/catch` it will close it anyway, but don't take my word on that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131377/socket-programming-multiple-client-to-one-server